# Does this violate any testing principles?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine.js to write JS unit tests, unsure if this type of code violates a testing principle of any kind:

```
expect(someObject).toNotBe(undefined || null);
```

as opposed to

```
expect(someObject).toNotBe(undefined);
expect(someObject).toNotBe(null);
```

Even though `null` and `undefined` are different, for the purposes of my test I don't (think I) care which one it is.

Comment: Then just pass `null` if you don't care, since that's what will be passed in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undefined || null` returns `null`, as `undefined` is falsy:

```
> undefined || null
null
```

Your first example is actually equivalent to the second line of your second example, which is:

```
expect(someObject).toNotBe(null);
```

Also, `toNotBe` [is deprecated](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers):

> The old matchers `toNotEqual`, `toNotBe`, `toNotMatch`, and `toNotContain` have been deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please change your specs to use `not.toEqual`, `not.toBe`, `not.toMatch`, and `not.toContain` respectively.

You may want to check for equality (not identity!) with `null`, as `false != null`, but `undefined == null`:

```
expect(someObject).not.toEqual(null);
```

If `someObject` being `false`, `0`, `[]`, etc. is also undesirable, you could also do:

```
expect(someObject).toBeTruthy();
```

Otherwise, you should write your own matcher.

Comment: Answered all of my questions & more. Brilliant answer, thanks.